# Node.js/Express duplicate req.param key when error

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, mongoose

When my node.js/express server hits an error from failure of saving an object (a post request), the `req.param` key duplicates.

For example, my node.js code:

```
User.create({
username: req.param("username")
});
```

where `req.param("username")` is "Tom"
When the above code triggers an error, and I resend the same request again, `req.param("username")` becomes `["Tom","Tom"]`. Why is that and how can I prevent it?

Comment: To get any real help you'd need to actually show us some code, but I'd guess it's some middleware you've added or the post code is weird.

Comment: I don't think that's necessary thought. The first time I run the request to create a new user, it gives me an error. Then I call that same request and the req.param("username") duplicates.

Comment: What's the url of both requests and what does the express route definition look like (ex: `app.get('url_here/:id')`)

Comment: The request is app.post("/user/new", user.postNewUser). The first time it is called req.param("username") is just Tom. The second time it is called, it becomes ["Tom","Tom"]

Comment: If you're trying to read from the body you should use `req.body`, not `req.params`.  The params are for url parsing.

Comment: I'm not using req.params. I'm using another function called req.param("username"). req.param is different from req.params in that req.param includes the body params also

Comment: I'd try with just `req.body`.  From the express docs: Direct access to req.body, req.params, and req.query should be favoured for clarity - unless you truly accept input from each object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, the duplicate param has nothing to do with the backend code. I passed in duplicate params in the front end form.